# pip: egg_info failed with error code 1

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've got a Raspberry Pi with Python 3.4.2 on Linux. When I try to install Thingspeak executing this command:

`pip install thingspeak`

I get this error:

```
 setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sk0Blx/thingspeak
```

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Give us the entire error output, not just one line.

Comment: There is only another line, that says:

Comment: Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log

Comment: setuptools_scm.version.SetuptoolsOutdatedWarning: your setuptools is too old (<12)

This is the last line before the error message

Comment: Well then, have you tried updating setuptools (and probably pip along with it)? If you installed them with a distro `python3-setuptools` and `python3-pip` or the like, use your package manager to try to upgrade; if not, use `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`.

Comment: When I try: pip install --upgrade setuptools pip , I get this: Can't roll back setuptools; was not uninstalled

Comment: I'm just curious what os you are running on your Raspberry Pi that come with Python 3.4?  The latest Raspian Stretch come with Python 3.5 pre-installed. BTW, for Raspberry Pi, `pip` is for python 2.7, `pip3` is for python 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

`pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` resolved the problem for me.

I had already done `pip install --upgrade pip` so it was really `setuptools` that needed the upgrade